# How to send null string using spinner on android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

How to submit spinner selecteditem text via btnup and why selectedReport on btnup cases is declared not used?I have search hard enough to solve this but i still blankon  what i need to do in order to get text on spinner to suit the coding.

```
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, uploadImageName;
Button bLogout;
ImageView viewImage;
Button b,btnup;
private String selectedReport = null;



} private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    //Array list of report to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Crime");
    list.add("Bribery");
    list.add("Schools problem");
    list.add("Homeless");
    list.add("Rural Problems");
    list.add("Public Transport");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();


        switch (parent.getId()) {

            case R.id.spinner:

                if (selectedReport != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Report you select is " + selectedItem,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                selectedReport = selectedItem;
                break;
        }


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogout:
            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnup:
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) viewImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            String selectedReport = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your views before onCreate in your class:

```
UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
EditText etName, etAge, etUsername, uploadImageName;
ImageView viewImage;
Button b, bLogout, btnup;
Spinner spinner;
String selectedReport;
```

In your onCreate, add the following:

```
String[] list = {"Crime", "Bribery", "Schools Problem", "Homeless", "Rural Problems", "Public Transport"}
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Report selected: " + list[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //You can remove this switch statement, if you don't need it.
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 1:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 2:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 3:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 4:
                //Do something
                break;
            case 5:
                //Do something
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }
});
```

I am assuming here that you have already set an onClickListener to your buttons in onCreate.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogout:
            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnup:
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) viewImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
            selectedReport = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the  explaination? @Hussein El Feky

Comment: I see that you have added onClick method, but you didn't add a listener to your buttons. So I fixed that.

Comment: i have listener in my codin just i erased them SO said i had nothing to say because its all codin

Comment: I am just a little confused. Why did you create a special class for your spinner? You can write this code in a normal activity. It's much simpler. I can solve your question by doing it in a normal activity. Do you want me to do that?

Comment: PLS HELP ME @Hussein El Feky

Comment: Check my updated answer. If you need more help, tell me.

Comment: how to submit the selected report with btnup? @Hussein El Feky

Comment: Updated my answer again. I hope that's what you want.

Comment: how to send it with basicnamevalupair?  @Husein El Feky

Comment: What do you mean by "basicnamevalupair"? Can you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: i want to send it to database

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences or SQLiteDatabase, but what exactly do you want to save?

Comment: selected report so the coding will like this

Comment: protected Void doInBackground (Void...params){
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("selectedreport" ));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("report"));
                HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

Comment: or spinner use somethin related to adapter to send it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you very well. So you want to send the string "selectedReport" with another string to your server or something?

Comment: oh we do not need that basicnamevaluepair to send selected report to database?..nevermind,so if do this spinner how you want to send it to database?

Comment: Do you want to save that string in a database for your app like SharedPreferences, or save it on your **server** database...? I don't know what you want exactly.

Comment: i want to send it to mysql